# Create table from list of tags lists in R

Tags: r, list, tags

I have a big list with tags in R. Example:

```
[[1]]
[1] "A" "C" "E" "F"

[[2]]
[1] "B" "C" "G"

[[3]]
[1] "A"

[[4]]
[1] "B"

[[5]]
[1] "C" "E"

[[6]]
[1] "G"
```

And I need to built a table with two values: 1/(-1), which represents if row has the tag(1) or not(-1).

```
    "A" "B" "C" "E" "F" "G"
[1]  1  -1  -1   1   1  -1
[2] -1   1   1  -1  -1   1
[3]  1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
[4] -1   1  -1  -1  -1  -1
[5] -1  -1   1   1  -1  -1
[6] -1  -1  -1  -1  -1   1
```

Comment: anything you tried? Why did it not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
d1 <- mtabulate(l1)
d1[d1==0] <- -1
d1
#   A  B  C  E  F  G
#1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1
#2 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1
#3  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
#4 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1
#5 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1
#6 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1
```

#### data

```
l1 <- list(c("A", "C", "E", "F"), c("B", "C", "G"), "A", "B", 
    c("C", "E"), "G")
```

Comment: dunno why this answer has fewer downvote. This is THE answer.

Comment: I get a few warnings like this:Warning messages: 1: In as.vector(x[, i]) :
  Reached total allocation of 4077Mb: see help(memory.size). Is it mean that table is built unproper?

Comment: @Zana It means that you have a big dataset and it reached the memory limit

Comment: So what can I do to built this table?

Comment: @Zana Use a machine with a bigger RAM size

Answer (score 7):

Here's an approach for you.

First, we name our list (otherwise we cannot use `stack`):

```
names(dat) <- 1:length(dat)
```

Then we turn it to long:

```
dat2 <- stack(dat)
```

Making our table is now easy:

```
res <- with(dat2, table(ind, values))
res[res==0]<--1

>res
   values
ind  A  B  C  E  F  G
  1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1
  2 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1
  3  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
  4 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1
  5 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1
  6 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1
```

data used:

```
dat <- list(c("A","C","E","F"),c("B","C","G"),"A","B",c("C","E"),"G")
```

Comment: Very nice. Once you obtained `dat2`, also `table(rev(dat2))*2-1` seems to work. Or also directly `table(rep(seq_along(dat),lengths(dat)),unlist(dat))*2-1`.